# Multiple transporters in one elevator

Tags: anylogic, lift

Hi again a new question about lifts in Anylogic,

Is there an manner to simulate that if there are multiple transporters waiting at an elevator that they can together take an lift (since the lift has a capacity of 3)?

Thanks,
Aron

Comment: even though it's perfectly possible with your own custom elevator agent, it's not possible with the lift that is available in anylogic... that one can take only 1 agent

Comment: Thanks @felipe, Is there anywhere an example with this custom elevator agent as far as you know?

Comment: i have done custom elevators, it's not hard... just a good level of agent-based, but i have no idea where you can find a public one

Comment: But how should it think about the logic behind it as agent? I've no clue at the moment haha, just like an transporter agent which transports something but than it transports it from one floor to another floor?

Comment: i might create an example for you in the next weeks :)